# LimitRequestBody not preventing large upload

Tags: apache, security, denial-of-service

I am having a problem with the LimitRequestBody directive. Although it will return a 413 error for a file that exceeds the limit (the standard "413 Request Entity Too Large" page), it doesn't appear to do what I intended it to do: prevent the abuse of bandwidth using the file upload box.

My LimitRequestBody is set to 3MB. Any file under 3MB is accepted, any file over 3MB gives 413 error as I expect. Uploading a 5MB file, and watching both a local data counter and the Linode data counter, I see the bandwidth increase by 5MB, despite the fact that the 413 error is returned.

Am I misunderstanding the way this works? What I want to do is prevent Apache from even accepting any request over 3MB, to prevent a malicious user from repeatedly uploading a large file and sapping my allocated server bandwidth. If this is not the way to prevent it, how do I do so? If this is, what am I doing wrong? I have tried placing LimitRequestBody both outside and inside the VirtualHost tags.

Comment: [Related](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201001.mbox/%3c5caa982e1001091827v58ece581ra2ec8476aa3a135f@mail.gmail.com%3e). In short: you can't really prevent data being sent to you if the receiving party doesn't listen to it.